# Yii2 form inside bootstrap modal

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, yii2, bootstrap-modal, active-form

In case of putting ActiveForm inside bootstrap modal, all assets registered again, causing jquery conflict and affects performance.
How can i control assets registered from ActiveForm noting that I need its validation and not need other scripts.

[image]

Comment: helpful : https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/4522

Comment: Thank you @Incognito this was hepful and solved my problem.
However i think this must be solved with better solutions in yii.

Answer (score 0):

Insert this code before: `return $this->renderAjax()`

```
Yii::$app->assetManager->bundles = [
  'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapPluginAsset' => false,
  'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset' => false,
  'yii\web\JqueryAsset' => false,
];
```